# Highlighting words and string in a html span programatically

Tags: html, string, highlight, cpu-word

I am writing a web application. In that, we are displaying a large text in a span control. The text may have several sentences (string of words). I want to highlight a few words and a few sentences in a separate color.

The large text displayed in the span is the output of a service.
Service2 will return few words as an array, those words should be highlighted as bold.
Service3 will return few sentences if those sentences present in the large text those sentences should be highlighted with some color.

Hope I am clear on my question. Experts, please help.

Comment: Are you ok with using jQuery?

Comment: Can you add the code that you have tried?

Comment: yes, I am ok to use jQuery

Comment: Don't have coloring code, but here is the code I used to display the large test

<div id="largetext-item" class="largeText">Large Text</div>
<span style="font-size:17px;white-space: pre-line;">{{cs.downloadtable.data.text}}</span>
</div>

Comment: Sorry but that is not enough information. Please use the snippet function and write a small example of your data or there are too many ways to interpret your data. Searching for words and highlighting them is not that hard however.